# GNU Make: read/write local variables or at least assigning lists with $(let)?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to use local variables in my makefiles to prevent possible interference with variables defined elsewhere with the same name. Make provides the $(let) internal function, but it seems to be quite limited.

It's not described in the documentation, but the local variables created this way seem to be read only. Assignments inside the let scope are silently ignored, the variables retain their initial values.

```
$(let a b,1 2, $(eval a=3) $(info a=$a b=$b))
```

This will output a=1 b=2, despite the a=3 assignment. The variables are not real variables but constants. If that's the case, at least an error/warning message would be great.

Another issue is that it's not possible to assign lists to the variables, as the first variable would assume the first element of the first list, the second variable would assume the second element of the first list and so on. Eventually the last variable would assume all the remaining elements from the first list and all element from all subsequent lists. This is documented, but it's not really what's needed in practical build systems.

Could somebody cast some light here, what's wrong with $(let), how can it be used properly, or is there any other way to define local vars in make?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really that local variables in `let` are read-only per se, it's that there's no good way to modify them.  When you run `$(eval ...)` that creates an entirely new makefile parser object (at least conceptually) and any operations you run inside that parser object are happening at global scope.  So any variables you set inside the `$(eval ...)` take effect globally but are NOT visible inside the `$(let ...)` because the `let` function creates a new local scope that hides the global variables.

So for example:

```
$(let a b,1 2, $(eval a=3) $(info local a=$a b=$b))
$(info global a=$a b=$b)
```

will give:

```
local a=1 b=2
global a=3 b=
```

It's not clear what you REALLY want to do, but the answer to the situation here is that you can't use `eval`, you need to use more `let` to create a new private scope with a different value:

```
$(let a b,1 2, $(let a,3, $(info local a=$a b=$b)))
$(info global a=$a b=$b)
```

yields:

```
local a=3 b=2
global a= b=
```

Regarding assigning lists, you're right but we'd need to see an example of what you're trying to do.  Most likely you're just thinking about it the wrong way (at least, the wrong way from make's perspective).

Just to remind, makefile syntax is not, and does not try to be, a complete programming language.  It's a very limited text processing language.  The less "programming" you try to do in a makefile the happier you'll be.  If you really want a full programming language in your build tool there are other options than make.  Alternatively you can build GNU Make with Guile support embedded and invoke Guile functions to perform complex operations.

Comment: Thanks, got it! Then $(let) is no good for me. Have no problems yet just afraid of possible variable collisions as the project is quite complicated. This build system creates rules based on what's found on the disk, and not only compiles but generates code from AUTOSAR modules etc... Actually you already helped a lot with it and it works fine.

Comment: Using more $(let) might be a solution. Nested $(let) should solve the issue with the lists, too. However, I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to open a new $(let) scope anytime the value needs to be changed. Might be better not touching and paying attention to the variable names instead :)

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to use `let`.  By definition `let` creates a local variable that goes away when it finishes evaluating.  So I don't see how it would be useful for creating local variables for defining rules unless you are going to try to put the entire makefile inside one big `let` function or something like that; that would be a total nightmare to figure out all the expansion issues.  That's definitely not what `let` is for.  I would recommend coming up with a naming convention.  It's not checked for you by tools but it's pretty simple.

Comment: One example to suggest.  Suppose you make a rule that says "all variables that start with `__` are local to the makefile".  Then you can remove all variables like by adding something like this: `$(foreach v,$(filter __%,$(.VARIABLES)),$(eval undefine $v))` to the start of each makefile where you want to "clear the decks".

Comment: The issue is with functions calling each other. Assume that one function iterates through a list of modules with foreach, storing the current module in m. And in foreach we call another function that uses the variable m for different purposes. In usual programming languages I'd make m local in the called function to avoid interference. Let would have been cool, but I can live without it. Everything works but care has to be taken to avoid colliding variable names.

Comment: `let` is fine to use within function calls like `foreach`.  That's what it was created for, more or less.  The question is what you mean by "storing the current module in m".  Basically, if you're trying to create complex for loops or other and using **eval** inside them to try to set variables, you will have lots of problems.  That's not how makefiles are designed to work.

Comment: Should you be interested I'm happy to show you what am I doing. I can't share the project here (the build system I can). A lot of cool stuff is possible with GNU make. It works, I'm just looking for ways to make it easier of overview and maintain. Yes there are complex foreach loops and many eval inside setting variables and calling functions.